# Can I pass in Common Interface type as parameter to method

Tags: java, interface

Language : Java

SO I have a bunch of interface files auto generated by middleware. All of them have a similar structure that I want to access. Is there a way to pass them interchangeably in a method  . Something similar to this

```
private void setDataToInterfaceFile(String dataTobeSet,Interface interface){
   interface.setString(dataTobeSet)
}
```

and use this something like this

```
setDataToInterface("Set me to 1",Interface_1)
setDataToInterface("Set me to 2",Interface_2)
```

Comment: you cannot set data to interface, probably you need to pass instance of the class which implements interface

Comment: yes since interfaces have only method signatures, but classes and abstract classes have implementations to the methods

Comment: If you `interface` is named `Interface` (which would be a terrible choise for a name) and `Interface_1` , `Interface_2` and `interface` (which you have to rename, as mentioned by bradimus) are of type `Interface`, then yes, that would work (those names though....).

Comment: Note `interface` is a key word in java, so you'll have to rename your parameter.

Comment: Yes, you can declare a parameter to have an interface type, and within the method use methods in the interface. When you call the method, you'll need to provide an object whose class implements the interface.

Comment: That's using abstraction to remove all information.  Might as well just pass Object.  I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: If `Interface_1` and `Interface_2` are the instance of classes which are implemen same interface which you say `Interface`, then you can.

Comment: Nope Interface_1 , Interface_2 are completely independent that is the trouble.

Comment: This interfaces a used to INTERFACE but you can't pass them.

Comment: If the generated interfaces don't extend a common interface, you could **wrap** instances of those interfaces in objects that do.

Comment: I did think about that but the thing is it makes system unstable.Since when this gets autogenerated the common interface will go away and someone will have to manually put it back which is a pain

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you modify the generated code in any way. You would write a common interface, and wrap instances of the generated interfaces in classes that implement the common interface. You would place the common interface and its implementations in code that is **version-controlled and outside the generated code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setDataToInterface("Set me to 1",Interface_1)

`Interface_1` isn't the interface itself. It is an instance of a class implementing the interface.

A class implementation can have multiple interfaces. And this interfaces can declare methods with the same signature.

Declare the "similar structure" of all your auto-generated interfaces within an extra interface:

```
interface Interface
{
  void setString(String text);
}
```

Then an implementation of the auto-generated `Interface_1` like

```
class Interface_1_Impl implements Interface, Interface_1
{
  @Override
  public void setString(String text)
  {
    // ...
  }
}
```

can be used as parameter of `setDataToInterfaceFile()`.

This design pattern is called **class adapter**.